# How to insert the default time correctly?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to insert a data, automatically generate a time and date. How to achieve?
As shown below:

[image]

Comment: What are your questions? Please provide more details to your question. Whatever you have written here is already visible in the screenshot you have provided.

Comment: thank you for @PaulVarghese  answer sincerely !The problem is solved.